# Simpler Methods Geometry

Tags: geometry

[image]In $△ABC$, $∠A = 2∠B$  , $CD$ bisects $∠ACB$ , $AC =11cm$ and $AD = 2cm$. Find the length, in cm, of $BC$. Attached is the figure of the question

I already solved it using the Angle Bisector Theorem and sine and cosine law, but is pretty tedious to do. I am asking for solutions that would be a lot quicker.

Solution:
My system of equations:

$ 11^2 +2^2 -44\cos2A = x^2 + \frac{4x^2}{121} - \frac{4x^2\cos A}{11}$

$BD = \frac{2BC}{11}$

$\frac{\sin2A}{CD} = \frac{\sin CAD}{11}$

$\frac{\sin A}{CD} = \frac{\sin CDB}{x}$

Solving these systems would give us 13.

Comment: Could you attach the figure for this question? It's not clear what is $D$.

Comment: Try Stewart's Theorem.

Comment: Im trying but what would you do after getting CD in terms of BC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
This is another way to do it.
Locate a point $M$ on $BC$ , such that $MC$ equals $11$. Join $AM$ , $MD$.           Let the intersection of $AM$ and $CD$ be $O$.

For convenience , let $$\angle ACD = \angle DCB = x \\∠CAD = 2y\\ ∠CBD = y$$ where $DC$ is the $\angle$ bisector.

$\triangle ACM$ is isosceles. This implies the base angles are equal and are $$\frac{180-2x}{2} = \frac{3y}{2}$$ 
(Since $180-2x = 3y$).

Also , $\triangle$s $AOC$ and $MOC$ are congruent. This further implies $\triangle AOD$ and  $\triangle MOD$ are congruent **(SAS)**.
 $$\angle OAD = 2y- \frac{3y}{2} = {y\over 2}$$  which implies $\angle OMD$ also equals $y/2$ **(CPCT)**.

Also , $DM = AD = 2$ (equal base angles).
We have,
$$\angle MDB = 2*{y\over 2} = y$$
Therefore , $MD = MB = 2$ (equal base angles).
Therefore, $$BC  = MC + MB = 11+2 = \boxed{13}  $$